# Facing "Installing profile for com.example.instagram" error while using flutter run

Tags: flutter, firebase, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-firestore

Tried changing the dependencies and plugins in build.grade of both android and app level but still it is still not resolving.It keeps on showing "Installing profile for com.example.instagram" and not progressing further.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4F4V.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrRLd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrEW9.png)

My main.dart is

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // initialise app based on platform- web or mobile
  if (kIsWeb) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: const FirebaseOptions(
          apiKey: "AIzaSyAzCAg_P6DtHV80cPmhkGKkpGDQu5wifrQ",
          appId: "1:885652404368:web:3963c3be5a585bd1b44015",
          messagingSenderId: "885652404368",
          projectId: "instaproject-eb5ea",
          storageBucket: 'instaproject-eb5ea.appspot.com'),
    );
  } else {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
  }
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

It appears that if kIsWeb = false, Firebase initializes with no parameters. Maybe that is causing this.

Comment: @Roy, how do I initalise it?

Comment: Add in the 'options' parameter when you initialize Firebase as per what you put in if (kIsWeb)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Roy, what should be the value of the parameters, for the web I got the values on the firebase only, the else statement is for android and ios.

Comment: The value of the parameters should be the same, as you're connecting to the same Firebase project.